# Remove square brackets from list

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
list1 = [['123'], ['456'], ['789']]
```

I want to convert this list into a string and later store it into a column in a database in this form:

```
123 / 456 / 789
```

I tried doing this:

```
s2 = ", ".join(repr(e) for e in list1)
print(s2)
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
['123'], ['456'], ['789']
```

Any ideas on what should I do next to get the desired output?

Comment: Do you only want to do this for printing? but keep the underlying list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close, but what you want to do is flatten your list of lists first, then convert to string. Like this:

```
" / ".join([item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist])
```

Comment: Best solution, should use `"/ ".join` though

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain`

```py
import itertools

list1 = [['123'], ['456'], ['789']]
", ".join(itertools.chain(*list1))
# => '123, 456, 789'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [['123'], ['456'], ['789']]

st = [ '/' + x[0]  for x in list1]

st = ''.join(st)

print(st)
```

**output**

/123/456/789

Answer (score 0):

Since you have lists in the list, you need to get the first indice so this helps you

```
" / ".join(map(lambda x:x[0],list1))
```

Comment: This is bad practice, there are [more clear functions for that](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Additionally, list comprehensions are almost always preferred over map

Comment: Yes you are right, my answer is just another way of how the question can be answered. After all this is not the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically only ever want the first element of a sublist even if it's got more than one element, then I think this one-liner is the clearest:

```
s2 = ' / '.join(  x[0] for x in list1 )
```